# Need/Usablity of Application Class Android?

Tags: android

Can Somebody can tell what is need of application class . I have read many blog and question about Application Class and all of them said that it used for saving global state variable . 
 Now , in my current application i am also saving states of many variables by using inheritances . I have a base **Activity** class in which i have defined all listener and static variable which  can inherited in all the other activity .

Now Please tell me disadvantages of my system if there is some :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application class is essentially a singleton that lives for the lifetime of the application. Given that fact, its an easy place to share globals. The other use it has is getting the application context which is useful for such things as background mode database access.

You don't have to use it as a means to share data. Its just one of the easy ways to do it.

Its actually not safe to use the activity as an application storage location like you are doing. On phones with low memory or where your app was run a long time ago what will happen is the activity can be destroyed but the app instance is not destroyed. This would result in your activity being restarted and all your statics in the base activity are wiped out when you expect them to be populated. If you want to guarantee that variables live for the lifetime of the application put them in the application class (or a class instantiated by the application class). If you want to guarantee they live for the life of the Activity then you can do what you are currently doing. Just remember whenever an Activity is not visible on the screen, there are no guarantees the OS won't kill it and restart it later when/if the user reopens that activity.

If you want the statics to be stored in an Activity and live through an Activty being destroyed and recreated then that can be done also. [See the activity documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html); Look for the section on Saving Persistent State. You would need to save your activity state when it could be killed and restore it later when it is recreated.

If you need the data to live longer then look into saving the data into a file or database.

Comment: me being noob , my design also create a base class as singleton . So i wouldn't consider this point as advantage . Can please point out disadvantage of my design over Application class . So that i can decide weather to change my design or not .

Comment: Sorry there is not nearly enough info to tell you if your implementation is good.

Comment: k. In my current design i have base-Activity in which all the static variable is defined and all the common listeners . Now whenever i want to create a new Activity i have to extent this Base-activity.